# Maven seems to refuse loading remote repos

Tags: git, maven

I'm trying to load a library (Neo4j Spatial, to be precise) with Maven. I specified the following repositories, as told in the README.md of Spatial:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>neo4j-contrib-releases</id>
    <url>https://raw.github.com/neo4j-contrib/m2/master/releases</url>
    <releases>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
  </repository>
  <repository>
    <id>neo4j-contrib-snapshots</id>
    <url>https://raw.github.com/neo4j-contrib/m2/master/snapshots</url>
    <releases>
      <enabled>false</enabled>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
    </snapshots>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

However, I get this error:

```
The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library   'C:\Users\root\.m2\repository\org\neo4j\neo4j-spatial\0.15-neo4j-2.2.3\neo4j-spatial-0.15-neo4j-2.2.3.jar'
```

Which suggests that Maven only searched my local repository and refused looking at the specified remote repositories at all. Any idea what is going on and what to do about it?

Comment: Perhaps it's not looking because those URLs result in 404s.

Comment: They should not. I copied the repo information from the Spatial (online GitHub) readme today.

Comment: OK, that happens using a browser to check, but `curl -L -O https://raw.github.com/neo4j-contrib/m2/master/releases/org/neo4j/neo4j-spatial/0.15-neo4j-2.2.3/neo4j-spatial-0.15-neo4j-2.2.3.jar` works just fine. Try running maven with -X command line option so that you can see what it's doing. Also add a -U to force it reattempt a failed download.

Comment: Ah yes, that would be good. Any ways to enable logging from Eclipse?